# Java Coverity indefinite wait error on lock statement

Tags: java, coverity

Relatively new to Java but tasked with looking at Coverity defects. Is this one as simple as I think? (I can't convince the code owner.)

```
 50       // this method is used when the program is run as a pojo.
 51        public static void main(final String[] args) {
 52
 53                startProgram();
 54
 55                // keep this here, for console app, needs to create a loop, but not for AS apps.
 56                lock = new Object();
 57

loop_outside_lock_insufficient: Because this loop occurs outside the locked region, it cannot be a sufficient check of the wait condition. The value of the wait condition may change between the check of the loop condition and the call to wait.
 58                while (!finished) {

lock_acquire: Acquiring lock program.lock.
 59                        synchronized (lock) {
 60                                try {

CID 711645 (#1 of 1): Indefinite wait (BAD_CHECK_OF_WAIT_COND)wait_cond_improperly_checked: The wait condition prompting the wait upon program.lock is not checked correctly. This code can wait for a condition that has already been satisfied, which can cause a never-ending wait.

Refactor the code to protect the call to wait with a loop that rechecks the wait condition inside the locked region.
 61                                        lock.wait();
 62                                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
 63
 64                                        log.error(e.getStackTrace());
 65                                }
 66                        }
 67                }
 68
 69        }
```

I think I just want to change this to

```
synchronized(lock)
    while(!finished){
        try lock.wait();
        catch(InterruptedException e)
            log.error(e.getStackTrace());
        }
```

Does that make sense? Do I really just need to move the while loop inside the lock statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `finished` as `volatile`. Then your solution is okay.

Comment: I had to lookup volatile. Found good information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java. If there is only one method that sets `finished` I should still use the `volatile` flag, but can I actually get rid of `synchronized`?

Comment: No, that's needed for wait().

Comment: Moving the code and adding volatile worked for me too but I don't fully understand why Coverity complained in the first place. Even after reading the reason why, it is still unclear as to the issue.